# Test cases to performClick for custom ClicklLstener

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso, robolectric

I have created one custom click listener like below:

```
abstract class SingleClickListener : View.OnClickListener {
    private var lastTimeClicked: Long = 0
    private val defaultInterval: Int = 1000
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTimeClicked < defaultInterval) {
            return
        }
        lastTimeClicked = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        performClick(v)
    }

    abstract fun performClick(v: View)
}
```

And then in my fragment I have used like below :

```
binding.textview.setOnClickListener(object : SingleClickListener() {
            override fun performClick(v: View) {
                //navigate to next screen
            }
        })
```

Now I want to write a test case to perform this custom click. I have tried like below but it is not working and if I'll remove SingleClickListener then the same test case is working fine.

```
val fragmentScenario = launchFragmentInContainerAndGetFragmentScenario()
            fragmentScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
                val textview = fragment.view?.findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.textview)

                textview?.performClick()
            }
```

Can anyone help me how can I call custom ClickListener's performClick function through test case?

Comment: What are you triyng to achieve: click only once, double click or click after some interval?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` which returns elapsed milliseconds since boot.
But in unit tests with robolectric you will have Zero for the result of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` call. Hence, `0 - 0 < 1000 => always true` in unit tests.

You can just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

```kotlin
abstract class SingleClickListener : View.OnClickListener {

  private var lastTimeClicked: Long = 0
  private val defaultInterval: Int = 1000
  override fun onClick(v: View) {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (now - lastTimeClicked < defaultInterval) {
      return
    }
    lastTimeClicked = now
    performClick(v)
  }

  abstract fun performClick(v: View)
}
```